# Why is use of the phrase "for God's sake" often considered sinful?

Tags: sin, christian-living, names-of-god

I often hear this on some people even in games, who use the phrase "for God's sake" or something similar ("for God's sakes," etc.)

I don't see how this can be considered sinful or blasphemous, considering passages like Isaiah 43:25 and Matthew 10:22:

> Isaiah 43:25
>   "I, even I, am he who blots out your transgressions, For My [God] own sake, and remembers your sins no more.
>
> Matthew 10:22
>   You will be hated for my name sake

Here's the meaning of `Sake` -

[image: sake]

The no.3 definition used this phrase. My question is:

**On what basis is it said that a sin is committed when using this phrase?  Why is it blasphemous?**

I suspect that this will be considered "taking God's name in vain."  But how could that be distinguished from me saying "For His name sake I will repent or I will do this and that."  In the back of my mind, I know this depends on how strong the phrase is delivered and the context / circumstances. I just want to a little enlightenment to this.

Comment: Welcome! As originally formulated, your question wasn't a particularly good fit for our site, since not all people who consider themselves Christians agree that using this phrase is sinful.  I've edited your question to make it more suited for us, while hopefully still asking what you'd like to know.  Feel free to make further edits.  If you haven't already done so, I hope you'll take a minute to take the [tour] and learn [how this site is different from others](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/a/1809/21576).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Violating Commandments is commonly linked to sin

For *an* official teaching, the Catholic Church's teaching is that careless references to God violates the Second Commandment (Third Commandment in some other denominations).  Other denominations may have similar points of view, but to keep this answer concise I confine it to the Catholic view.

Exodus 20:7

> You shall not take the name of the LORD, your God, in vain. For the
>   LORD will not leave unpunished him who takes his name in vain.

From the Catechism ...

> [CCC 2143](http://www.vatican.va/archive/ENG0015/__P7I.HTM#$28T)  "The Lord's name is holy." For this reason man must not
>   abuse it. He must keep it in mind in silent, loving adoration. He will
>   not introduce it into his own speech except to bless, praise, and
>   glorify it.

See also Psalm 29:2 (KJV)

> Give *unto the Lord the glory due unto his name*; worship the Lord in
>   the beauty of holiness.

And Psalm 113:2-3 (KJV)

> Blessed be the name of the Lord from this time forth and for evermore.
>   From the rising of the sun unto the going down of the same *the
>   Lord's name is to be praised*.

To use "For God's sake" per your definition 3 -- as a sign of annoyance, impatience, or urgency -- does not bless, praise or glorify God.  That usage also goes against [the principle of Christian Charity<sup>1</sup>](http://www.vatican.va/archive/ENG0015/__P7Q.HTM).

> [CCC 2146](http://www.vatican.va/archive/ENG0015/__P7I.HTM#$28T) The second commandment forbids the abuse of God's name, i.e.,
>   every improper use of the names of God, Jesus Christ, but also of the
>   Virgin Mary and all the saints.

#### Pay respect where respect is due

In closing, St Augustine lays out the respect due to the Lord

> [God's] name is great when spoken with respect for the greatness of
>   his majesty.  God's name is holy when said with veneration and fear of
>   offending him.  *~ St. Augustine, De serm. Dom. in monte 2, 5, 19: PL 34, 1278.*

---

<sup>1</sup> [388. What is charity?](http://www.vatican.va/archive/compendium_ccc/documents/archive_2005_compendium-ccc_en.html) 
From CCC 1822-1829, and 1844)

> Charity is the theological virtue by which we love God above all
>   things and our neighbor as ourselves for the love of God. Jesus makes
>   charity the new commandment, the fullness of the law. “It is the bond
>   of perfection” (Colossians 3:14) and the foundation of the other
>   virtues to which it gives life, inspiration, and order. Without
>   charity “I am nothing” and “I gain nothing” (1 Corinthians 13:1-3).

Answer (score -2):

Since it is God, Himself, who enables us 'to do,' (or exist at all for that matter), it would be impossible for us to do anything for His "sake," - i.e. to "help," God.  For any person or "thing," to think it could "help," God is an insult ("blasphemy").

*Philippians 2:13 - For God is working in you, giving you the desire and the power to do what pleases Him.*

*John 15:5 - I am the vine; you are the branches. If you remain in me and I in you, you will bear much fruit; apart from me you can do nothing.*

*Colossians 1:16 - For in Him all things were created: things in heaven and on earth, visible and invisible, whether thrones or powers or rulers or authorities; all things have been created through Him and for Him.*

Comment: Welcome! Interesting interpretation; I hadn't thought of it that way.  If you'd like to strengthen your answer, you might consider adding sources to backup this analysis.  I hope you'll take a minute to review [how this site is different from others](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/a/1809/21576), and better understand how [your answer can be supported](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/692/21576).  Thanks!